# Receive mouse event on transparent windows

Tags: qt, qt4

I have main windows which is set to transparent to desktop, using

```
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

also within it is a webview again with transparent background:

```
    QPalette palette = webview->palette();
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::Base, Qt::transparent);
    view->page()->setPalette(palette);
```

Everything works ok, except that the mouse-event also passes through to window (opengl windows created and run by a new thread) below, where it is completely transparent.

How can we stop this behavior. I would like to have mouse to be handled in the webview itself?

Windows 7, Qt 4.8.1, VS2010